# User is not authenticated jswtoken

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jwt

I have created a login page and a about page the user will only access the about page if the user is logged in.
I am trying to authenticate the user by using the tokens generated while signing in, but the token is not getting authenticated even after signing in with the correct credentials. I don't know what is the problem?

This is code to my sign-in and token generating method

```
const express = require("express");
const { default: mongoose } = require("mongoose");
const router = express.Router();
const bcrypt = require("bcrypt");
const jwt = require("jsonwebtoken");
require("../db/conn");
const User = require("../model/userSchema");
const cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
const Authenticate = require("../middleware/authenticate");

router.use(cookieParser());

  //LOgin route
  router.post("/signin", (req, res)=>{
    if(!req.body.email || !req.body.password){
      return res.status(400).json({error: "Plz fill the required data"});
   }else{
    bcrypt.hash(req.body.password, 12, function (err, hash) { 
      User.findOne({email: req.body.email}, function (err, foundUser) {
        if(err){
          console.log(err);
        }else{
          if(foundUser){
            bcrypt.compare(req.body.password, foundUser.password, function (err, result) {
                  if(result){
                    return res.json({message: "successfully log in"})
                  }else{
                    return res.json({message: "incorrect password"});
                  }
              });
              const email = req.body.email;
              const token = jwt.sign(
                { user_id: foundUser._id, email },
                process.env.TOKEN_KEY,
                {
                  expiresIn: "720h",
                }
              );
              foundUser.tokens = foundUser.tokens.concat({token: token});
              foundUser.save();
              
              // res.status(200).json(foundUser);
              console.log(foundUser);
          }else{
            return res.status(400).json({message: "user not found"});
          };
        }
      })
    })
  }
  });

  //about us page
  router.get("/about", Authenticate, function (req, res) {
    console.log("about running");
    res.send(req.rootUser);
  });

module.exports = router;
```

this is the code to authenticate the user

```
require("dotenv").config({path: "./config.env"});  
const jwt = require("jsonwebtoken");
const User = require("../model/userSchema");



const Authenticate = async(req, res, next) =>{
    try {
        const token = req.cookies.jwtoken;
        const verifyToken = jwt.verify(token, process.env.TOKEN_KEY);
        const rootUser = await User.findOne({ _id: verifyToken._id, "tokens.token": token});
        if(!rootUser) {
            throw new Error("User not found")
        }
        req.token = token;
        req.rootUser = rootUser;
        req.userID = rootUser._id;
        next();
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
        return res.status(401).send("Unauthorized: No token provided");
    }

}

module.exports = Authenticate;
```

This is  react based code of: About-page to display it or not based on user's authenticity.

```js
 const navigate = useNavigate();
    const callAboutPage = async() =>{
        try {
            const res = await fetch("/about",{
                method: "GET",
                headers: {
                    Accept: "application/json",
                    "Content-Type" : "application/json"

                },
                credentials: "include"
            });
            const data = await res.json();
            console.log(data);
            if(!res.status === 200){
                const error = new Error(res.error);
                throw error;
            }

        } catch (err) {
            console.log(err);
            navigate("/login");
        } 
    }
```

Comment: You're trying to get the token from the cookies, but it seems that you don't set it somewhere from what I see. You should probably in your res if the user is found

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As said in the comment looks like there is a issue on the process for setting up the jwtoken, and when you sign in, you just need to find the user and compare the password, there is no need to do the hash with Bcrypt, since you're not registing new user, for example, i will use Async/await instead of callback function, in order for you to read it much more easier:

```
//Login route
router.post("/signin", async (req, res)=> {
        const { reqEmail, reqPassword } = req.body; //destructuring so less thing to write at the next step
    if(!reqEmail || !reqPassword) {
        return res.status(400).json({message: "Plz fill the required data"});
    } 
    try {
        const foundUser = await User.findOne({email: reqEmail})
            if(!foundUser) {
                return res.status(400).json({message: "Wrong username or password!"})
            }
        const result = await bcrypt.compare(reqPassword, foundUser.password);
            if(!result){
                return res.json({message: "Wrong username or password!"})
            } else {
               const accessToken = jwt.sign(
                    { user_id: foundUser._id, email: foundUser.email},
                     process.env.TOKEN_KEY,
                    { expiresIn: "720h",}
               );

 // I am confuse what are you trying to do here, in your place I would set up on the cookie since you do that on your authentification.
                res.cookie("jwt", accessToken, {
                    maxAge: 60000,  // 60 sec for testing
                    httpOnly: true,
                    sameSite: false,  //false only for dev
                    secure: false,   //false only for dev
                })
                res.status(200).json(foundUser);
            };
    } catch (error) {
        return res.status(500).json({message: `${error}`})
    }
```

Than the authentification middleware :

```
// ...
const Authenticate = (req, res, next) => {
    const accessToken = req.cookies.jwt

    if(!accessToken) {
        return res.status(401).json({error: "Unauthorized: No token provided"});
    }
        try {
            const user = jwt.verify(accessToken, process.env.TOKEN_KEY)
            if(user) {
                req.user = user
                return next();
            }
        } catch (error) {
            return res.status(403).json({error: "Forbidden token error"})
        }
}
```

about page component it's simple for now since you don't manage any state

```
const navigate = useNavigate();
const callAboutPage = async() =>{
    try {
        const res = await fetch("/about",{
            headers: {
                "Content-Type": "application/json"
            },
            credentials: "include"
        });
        if(res.status === 200){
          const data = await res.json();
          // set up the state for rendering 
          console.log(data);
        } else {
          // you can also create a state to catch the error message from the backend, in this case the response json should be move to above the if statement.
            throw new Error("You must log in to get access")
          // than you can display this error message, or from the backend using state for this bloc, and the catch bloc
          // navigate to /login
        }
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
        navigate("/login");
    } 
}
```

Comment: I tried it but it is accessing the about page even if the user is not logged in

Comment: well did you add an logout route for testing ? how do you know you're not authenticate, have you test your api route in Postman for ex ?

Comment: I re-started the server and in the browser about page was opening without logging in from there I supposed that maybe the authentication code is not working. Now I tested it in Postman: on accessing the "localhost:5000/about" without log in it gave "UnAuthorised: No token provided" and accessing the "localhost:5000/about" after log in it showed a blank page in the body section and a jwt token in the cookies section. Does it mean that the authentication code is working fine? But if it is working then why in browser I can access the about page without logging even after restarting the server?

Comment: Hm try to clear out the cookie from your testing site and retest ? as I say you should make a route to log out and clearout the cookie, even if you restart your server but you re using jwt and as long as you have it you don't need to relogin again.

Comment: I have created a logout route and tried it and even tried deleting browser cookies but still, I can access the about page in a browser without logging in. I tried it in the different browser too but the same problem. I think there is some problem in front-end of my About page code where I am making requests for the about page. Can you suggest some changes?

Comment: this is weird,, can you console.log(accessToken) on the Authenticate middleware when you try to acces your aboutpage ?

Comment: using postman i am getting a valid token but on browser if I go to about page it is showing "undefined" in console

Answer (score 0):

```
router.use(cookieParser());
```

Try to use cookieParser with app.use instead. (app from express instense)
Expample:

```
const app = express();
app.use(cookieParser());
```

and try to put it before server listening in index.js or app.js file.
Hope it help.